# How to query MongoDB using geoNear?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use the aggregate function, geoNear and near to locate distances depending on longtitude and latitude using mongodb .

```
`router.get('/devops' , (req,res,next) => {
   /*
   Devops.find({})
   .then((alldevops) => {
      res.send(alldevops);
   })
   */
  Devops.aggregate().near({
   near: [parseFloat(req.query.lng), parseFloat(req.query.lat)],
   maxDistance: 100000,
   spherical: true,
   distanceField: "dist.calculated"
  }).then((alldevops)=>{
     res.send(alldevops);
  });

});`
```

I am getting an error that says

> MongoError: geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 100000.0

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that your schema should be like jeo.json format which is specified below

```
{
  "other_key":"other_key_type"

 // this is important
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [Number] // it is [latitude, longitude], yes it is reverse way
  }

}
```

Now you have the schema insert the data into the database using this schema

Now you can apply geo near concept on your data by the following example

```
YourModal.aggregate([
    {
      $geoNear: {
        near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [16.51194, 80.735627] },
        distanceField: 'dist.calculated',
        includeLocs: 'dist.location',
        spherical: true
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        dist: 1
      }
    }
  ])
```

Here you will get many options but I have taken out the only dist from given coordinates.
I think this will give a brief idea to implement the geoNear query from the database